# How to change the program-->From "Submit Button" to "onchange javascript seleced" dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php, select, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am creating a page in JSP where I have a three related dropdown list
and once the user selects a value from first dropdown list called
"prefecture" then he has to click on the 'next' button and then the
related value is sent to second dropdown list called "line" then he
has to click again to 'next' button and then the related value is sent
to third dropdown list called "station" and last click  save button
then related company list will be appear from selected nearest
station. and my coding in below:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;padding:5px;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #777">
    <div>
        <div>
        <span id="wishtxt" style="color:#dd0000;font-size: 150%;display:none"></span>
        <form action="<?php echo REQUEST_PATH?>" id="form_eki">
    <?php if($h->is_action('index'))://------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------?>
        <input type="hidden" name="wish">


        <div>
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
            <select name="pref" tabindex="6" style="width: auto;">
            <option value="">-- select prefecture name --</option>
            <?php $h->pr_ops_pref($h->get_target_pref())?>
            </select>
            <button name="action" value="line" type="submit" tabindex="7">Next</button>
        </div>

    <?php elseif($h->is_action('line'))://------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------?>
            <input type="hidden" name="wish">
            <input type="hidden" name="pref">

            <div>
                 <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                <select name="pref" tabindex="6" style="width: auto;">
                <option value="">-- select prefecture name --</option>
                <?php $h->pr_ops_pref($h->get_target_pref())?>
                </select>
                <button name="action" value="line" type="submit" tabindex="7">Change</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php if($h->d('list_station')):?>


            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                <select name="line" tabindex="8" style="width: auto;max-width: 350px;">
                    <?php $h->pr_ops_db($h->d('list_line'),'line_cd',"line_name") ?>
                </select>
                <span>
                    <button name="action" val2ue="line" type="submit" tabindex="9">Change</button>
                </span>
            </div>

            <?php
                $imax = count($h->d('list_station'));
            ?>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <select id="station_cd" name="station_cd" style="width: auto;max-width: 350px;">
                <option value="" selected>-- Select the nearest station--</option>
                <?php for ($i=0;$i<$imax;$i++):?>
                <option value="<?php $h->pr_d("list_station/$i/station_cd");?>"><?php $h->pr_d("list_station/$i/station_name")?></option>
                <?php endfor;?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="clear" tabindex="4">back</button>　
                <button id="btn_eki" type="button" tabindex="4" style="color:red">save</button>
            </div>

        <?php elseif($h->d('list_line')):?>
            <h3 style="margin-top: 5px;">Select a railway line</h3>
            <?php
                $company_name = '';
                $imax = count($h->d('list_line'));
            ?>
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
            <select name="line" style="width: auto;max-width: 250px;">
                <optgroup label="">
                    <option value="" selected>-- Select nearest railway line --</option>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i<$imax; $i++):?>
            <?php if($h->d("list_line/$i/company_name") != $company_name):?>
                <?php $company_name = $h->d("list_line/$i/company_name");?>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="<?php echo $company_name;?>">
            <?php endif;?>
                    <option value="<?php $h->pr_d("list_line/$i/line_cd")?>"><?php $h->pr_d("list_line/$i/line_name")?></option>
            <?php endfor;?>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="clear" tabindex="4">back</button>　
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="line">Next</button>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endif;//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------?>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But Now i want to make it only three dropdown list and "onChange
select" and there will be no button for "Next" "Back" or "Save". When
i select "Prefecture" from first dropdown list the automitacaly will
be updated to "Line" second dropdown list and when i select second
dropdown list then automitacaly will be updated to "Station" third
dropdown list and finally auto saved in back-end and   related company
list will be appear from selected nearest station.

> Thanks for your information.I have changed in following way but when i
>   select "prefecture" from first dropdown list then the second dropdown
>   list called "line" will not appear... Can anybody help me to sort it out?
>
> my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pref_cd').on('change',function(){
        $('#line_cd').val('');
        $('#station_cd').val('');
        $('#form_eki').submit();
        return true;
    });
    $('#line_cd').on('change',function(){
        $('#station_cd').val('');
        $('#form_eki').submit();
        return true;
    });
    $('#btn_eki').click(function(){
        var $option = $('#station_cd option:selected');
        var station_cd = $option.val();
        window.parent.add_tag(station_cd, "", $('#wishtxt').html(),1);
        window.parent.$('#nearStForm' + $('input[name="wish"]').val()).slideUp();
    });
    $('.close').click(function() {
        window.parent.$('#nearStForm' + $('input[name="wish"]').val()).slideUp();
    });
    $('#btn_clear').click(function(){

    });
    $('#wishtxt').html($('#form_eki [name="wish"]').val());
});
```

> and i have deleted all buttons & changes programs are 
>   in First dropdownlist:

```
<select name="pref" id="pref" onChange="this.form.submit()" tabindex="6" style="width: auto;">
    <option value="">-- select prefecture name --</option>
    <?php $h->pr_ops_pref($h->get_target_pref())?>
</select>
```

> in Second dropdownlist:

```
<select name="line" id="line" onChange="this.form.submit()" tabindex="8" style="width: auto;max-width: 350px;">
    <?php $h->pr_ops_db($h->d('list_line'),'line_cd',"line_name") ?>
</select>
```

> in third dropdownlist:

```
<select id="station_cd" onChange="this.form.submit()" name="station_cd" style="width: auto;max-width: 350px;">
    <option value="" selected>-- Select the nearest station--</option>
    <?php for ($i=0;$i<$imax;$i++):?>
        <option value="<?php $h->pr_d("list_station/$i/station_cd");?>"><?php $h->pr_d("list_station/$i/station_name")?></option>
    <?php endfor;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On change of "prefecture" call an javascript function inside which call an ajax functionality.In this ajax call do the same thing as you performed inside form submit().On success of ajax call populate 2nd dropdown & do the same thing with 2nd dropdown also.

Comment: Thanks for your information.I have changed in above way but when i select "prefecture" from first dropdown list then the second dropdown list called "line" will not appear... Can anybody help me to sort it out?